# Use Ansible control master's IP address in Jinja template

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I would like to insert an IP address in to a J2 template which is used by an Ansible playbook. That IP adress is *not* the address of the host which is being provisioned, but the IP of the host from which the provisioning is done. Everything I have found so far covers using variables/facts related to the hosts being provisioned.
In other words: the IP I’d like to insert is the one in `['ansible_default_ipv4']['address']` when executing `ansible -m setup 127.0.0.1`.

I think that I could use a [local playbook](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html#local-playbooks) to write a dynamically generated template file containing the IP, but I was hoping that this might be possible “the Ansible way”.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I'm running into the same issue and curious what you ended up doing.

Comment: No, unfortunately not yet.

Comment: see my answer at
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34560622/best-way-to-get-the-ip-address-of-the-ansible-control-machine/39336170#39336170

Answer (score 4):

Just use this:

```
{{ ansible_env["SSH_CLIENT"].split()[0] }}
```

Comment: When using this in the J2 template with Ansible 1.9.4, I get a fatal error with message “AnsibleUndefinedVariable: One or more undefined variables: 'dict object' has no attribute 'SSH_CLIENT'”

Answer (score 2):

You can force Ansible to fetch facts about the control host by running the `setup` module locally by using either a `local_action` or `delegate_to`. You can then either register that output and parse it or simply use `set_fact` to give it a useful name to use later in your template.

An example play might look something like:

```
   tasks:
    - name: setup
      setup:
      delegate_to: 127.0.0.1

    - name: set ansible control host IP fact
      set_fact:
        ansible_control_host_address: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_eth0']['ipv4']['address'] }}"
      delegate_to: 127.0.0.1

    - name: template file with ansible control host IP
      template:
        src: /path/to/template.j2
        dest: /path/to/destination/file
```

And then use the `ansible_control_host_address` variable in your template as normal:

```
...
Ansible control host IP: {{ ansible_control_host_address }}
...
```

Comment: If I skip the `setup` task, provisioning works, but `ansible_control_host_address` contains the primary IPv4 of the VM which is being provisioned, not that of the Mac on which Ansible (BTW: v1.9.3) is installed. If I include the `setup` task, I get an error with message “unsupported parameter for module: delegate_to”

Comment: @BlueM Just noticed your comment - I'm sure you solved it by now but it sounds like your issue with the setup task is just indentation. If you indented `delegate_to` inside the `setup:` block then it is seen as a parameter to the setup module rather than a parameter to the task which is what it should be.

Comment: Thanks, @ydaetskcoR, for your comment – especially, as I did not solve the issue (but I stopped working on the project for which I needed this a short time after my question). I just tried it (Ansible 2.3.1.0 on OS X 10.12) with the changed indentation, but again: `Unsupported parameters for (setup) module: delegate_to. Supported parameters include: fact_path,filter,gather_subset,gather_timeout"}`. The fact that Ansible speaks of the “setup” module apperas as if the nesting as you intend it to be.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved the same problem (Ansible 2.7):

```
- name: Get local IP address
  setup:
  delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
  delegate_facts: yes

- name: Add to hosts file
  become: yes
  lineinfile:
    line: "{{ hostvars['127.0.0.1']['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'] }}   myhost"
    path: /etc/hosts
```

Seems to work like a charm. :-)

Comment: Trying this, I get `FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVarsVars object' has no attribute 'ansible_default_ipv4'"}`. I have hardly used Ansible in the last 2 years, so it may be I’m just missing something obvious … BTW, it’s Ansible 2.7.5 on macOS, and I tried to provision a local Debian Stretch in VirtualBox.

Comment: My example runs on ansible 2.7.5 on Arch Linux. I can imagine that macOS perhaps doesn't have the "ansible_default_ipv4" fact, but with a little debug message it should be pretty easy to figure out the correct key. Hope this helps!

Comment: Using this proposed solution because it works even after `become`. Also added a `run_once` and `when: 'hostvars["127.0.0.1"]["ansible_default_ipv4"] is not defined'` condition to `setup` to avoid multiple collections.